# How to add progress bar to Thread

Tags: android

I have a thread creating bitmap its take about 4 seconds and when starting activity program frozing 4 seconds.
I want to use progress bar in this time. How can i implement in thread? 
I'm giving Looper() problem when i added any progress bar to in Thread.

My thread:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
// this is the msg which will be encode in QRcode
                QRcode= QRCodeIDFromActivity;
                qrcodeTextview.setText("QRCodeID:"+QRcode);
                sharedqrtextview.setText(sharedqrfromactivity);
                try {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        wait(10);
// runOnUiThread method used to do UI task in main thread.
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {

                                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                                    bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(QRcode);
                                    qrCodeImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                } catch (WriterException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } // end of catch block

                            } // end of run method
                        });

                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Comment: You can't manipulate the UI from a thread other than the main thread. This includes adding elements to the UI. You would need to add it before starting your thread, keep a reference to it and remove it again in your `Runnable` started with `runOnUiThread`

Comment: is it mean? ; 1-  i will start before thread 
2- i will finish or dismiss in thread ? how can i put this elements show() and dismiss() ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can create a `ProgressDialog` before you initialize your thread: `final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);`. You can then show it before starting your thread: `progressDialog.show();`. You can dismiss it again from your runnable that is running on the ui thread: `progressDialog.dismiss();`